# Slate-tiled shower sill area is flaking and crumbling. How, please, can I stabilize it?

Tags: bathroom, tile

My slate shower stall has crumbling tiles at the hinges of the door and at the sill. Is there a product/procedure that I (basic paintbrush/hammer/screwdriver skills homeowner) can use to stabilize and seal this area with something that #1. is clear and #2. has a satin finish? I'd like not to weaken the door install by having the glass door removed and reinstalled after replacement of the damaged tiles, but I do have some tiles in storage. Is there more to the problem than I am seeing that would make the latter the only sensible (expensive) option?  Thank you
[image: powdery soft slate tiles]

Comment: I dunno...maybe a penetrating sealer?